# Should I remove unused screws from my frame?

Tags: maintenance, rust

Is it a bad practice to remove all the unused screws from my frame (i.e. for the mudguards, front/back racks)? Could rust be an issue? Even if the holes for the screw do not expose the inside of the frame?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you in the first place?

Comment: I've never seen a frame pre-stuffed with screws for hardware which doesn't come with it.  Screws do not protect from rust, and an aluminum frame doesn't need such protection anyway. (The screws themselves could rust if they are junk, not suitable for outdoor exposure.)

Comment: It's a Kona Sutra (thus a steel frame), I only mount the mudguards during the colder months and when it's raining.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're a weight weenie then your frame wouldn't even have those mounts.

Removing the screws might save you 10-20 grammes, which is less than a good dollop of mud, or under half a snackbar, or a quarter the weight of your spare tube.

If you're worried about rust, remove screw and apply some grease then refit.

If you're really worried about rust on the bike then fit mudguards, for which you'll need those screws anyway.

**Answer**: don't bother removing spare screws/bolts from your bike.

Comment: If you remove them because of weight, store them in a safe place and replace them with plastic (nylon) screws to plug the holes if needed. I do that with the holes for the bottle cages on the CX bike.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't.

You won't know where they are if you ever need them.